# Problems with translating MYSQL query using date_add function and time intervals for BQ

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery, intervals, dateadd

I have a query that runs on our MYSQL database.  It takes forever to run, so I would like to use BigQuery instead.  The relevant table (a.xxx) is already in the cloud, and I've tried adjusting the code for BQ, but I'm not having any luck.  The query basically pulls the number of individuals making purchases by day, and the number of those *same* individuals, who made another purchase 1-7 days after the initial purchase.  I would appreciate any help!!!!

Here is the query:

```
    select f.fts_date, 
count(distinct f.FTS_id) as FTS_count, 
count(distinct s.passportid) as SVS_count, 
(count(distinct s.passportid)/count(distinct f.FTS_id)) as return_rate 

from

(select passportid as FTS_id,addressid, date(signdatetime) as FTS_date from a.xxx
where  date(signdatetime)>'2015-6-10'  and fts="Y" and disposition="accepted") as f

left join a.xxx as s
on f.passportid=s.passportid and f.addressid=s.addressid and s.disposition="accepted" and 
s.signdatetime between date_add(f.signdatetime, 1, "DAY") and date_add(f.signdatetime, 7, "DAY")  

group by 1
```

Comment: Can you add the table definitions of the a.xxx table? Also this line:    and fts = "N"  looks like it is interesting: how can an alias (fts) be a value "N". Maybe it is wise not to use aliases which are also column names.

Comment: I changed the alias names and some of the column names so that it's less confusing.  Initially, I changed it so the code was more generic for the purposes of posting it in an online forum.

Comment: schema for relevant columns:  passportid, integer, nullable    addressid,integer,nullable   signdatetime, timestamp, nullable                 current error is:  Error: ON clause must be AND of = comparisons of one field name from each table, with all field names prefixed with table name.

Comment: Please format your code a bit better (use more line breaks). Also add a schema request or stuff like that in your question so it becomes more readable every time. Having said that: Try this: Replace:

s.signdatetime between date_add(f.signdatetime, 1, "DAY") and date_add(f.signdatetime, 7, "DAY") with: s.signdatetime > date_add(f.signdatetime, 1, "DAY") and s.signdatetime < date_add(f.signdatetime, 7, "DAY")

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery doesn't support INTERVAL keyword in DATE_ADD function, instead you should write it as

```
date_add(FTS_date, 1, "DAY")
```

See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#datetimefunctions for more details

Comment: thanks  changed code.  now I'm getting this error:  Error: ON clause must be AND of = comparisons of one field name from each table, with all field names prefixed with table name.

Comment: @Srini Hi Srini, I think this would be better asked as a new question, not simply a comment on an answer.